# Why object deformed in Follow Path (ctrl + p)?

Tags: path

I'm trying this method I found in youtube: https://youtu.be/ZgdobdXzKM4
But the problem is the child/duplicated objects deformed when applying the "Follow Path". What would be the reason deformed and what would be missing settings should I configure?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I do not know what you did wrong, but, I did everything that was shown on the video and it worked. Try again.
[image]

Comment: My bad, maybe I messed-up other configurations because of other previous tutorials. For now everything is good. I want to delete this question, very embarrassing. haha :D